# EEVEE Baking Time

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I would be thankful for an answer-orientation. 
I am working with EEVEE and  I would like to check and keep track of Baking times duration for different setting-qualities.   Is there a stamp or log to check ??

Thanks

Comment: Blender saves render stats as EXIF information under certain file formats

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; last I checked, Eevee doesn't support baking of lighting/texture information. What kind of baking do you mean, @Felipe?

Answer (score 0):

Properties > Metadata > Burn Into Image checkbox

[image: Metadata]

Comment: Yes,, but that is for the rendering time... i want to keep trak of baking lighting time..

Comment: How do you baking with eevee?